# Mysql : Replace characters and then insert in column

Tags: mysql, replace, insert, substring

I have appox. 10,000 batch of data that consisted of characters and it looks like

"ABCD" What I have to do is remove this quatation marks. I wonder If I can replace quotation marks into nothing or just substring characters part and insert into the columns where it was there.

Comment: Use the replace() function. What is unclear about that?

Comment: @juergend I just wonder when I got new string using replace, if I can update new string into the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you can give this a try

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COL_NAME = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM COL_NAME)
```

Where the col_name is the column containing the double quotes and table is the table which is having this dataset.